# Undefined index on template file

Tags: layout, template, array

I am attempting to echo out a message associated with a specific key in an array. I am getting undefined index and I cannot figure out why. My code is below:

```
<h1>RocketSnail Dynamic Template Editor</h1>
<p>Here you can edit which shipping type should take priority, as well as what message will show.</p>
<?php
$messagesArray = (array) Mage::helper('GOED_RocketSnail')->readFromJson(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/RocketSnail/typeandmessage.json');
$selectedShipType = $_GET['shiptype'];
$selectedMessage = $messagesArray[$selectedShipType];
foreach($messagesArray as $shipType => $message){
    echo "<a href='?shiptype=".$shipType."' >".$shipType."</a>";
    echo "<br />";
}
Mage::log($selectedMessage);
//Mage::log($selectedShipType);
//var_dump($messagesArray);
if(array_key_exists("16677", $messagesArray)){
    echo "Exists! String!";
}
if(array_key_exists(16677, $messagesArray)){
    echo "Exists! Int!";
}
if(array_key_exists(0, $messagesArray)){
    echo "Exists! What?!?";
}
echo $selectedMessage;
?>
```

`readFromJson` simply reads from a Json file and returns whatever the file contains. If I `var_dump($messagesArray)`, I get:

```
array(17) { ["16677"]=> string(4) "Here" ["31842"]=> string(2) "Is" ["16672"]=> string(1) "A" ["16673"]=> string(7) "Message" ["16674"]=> string(3) "For" ["16675"]=> string(4) "Each" ["16676"]=> string(8) "Possible" ["28492"]=> string(13) "Shipping_Type" ["26028"]=> string(2) "On" ["26319"]=> string(4) "Each" ["8066"]=> string(8) "Possible" ["8067"]=> string(4) "Item" ["34003"]=> string(2) "So" ["34002"]=> string(2) "We" ["51572"]=> string(3) "Can" ["25020"]=> string(6) "Change" ["25019"]=> string(7) "Content" }
```

When I log my `$_GET` request I have

> 2016-05-31T14:37:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): 16677

BUT! When I log `$selectedMessage`, I get

> 2016-05-31T14:40:49+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index:   in /var/www/html/app/design/adminhtml/default/desktop/template/goed/RocketSnailFilter.phtml on line 6

I'm stumped on this one. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: **EDIT:** I tried typecasting $selectedShipType to both a string and an int but that didn't help either. I'm surprised that neither "Exists! Int!" nor "Exists! String!" show on the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to figure this out. I'm sad to have been downvoted when this seems to be something others have experienced as well with no real answers. The error was coming from my readFromJson function. Apparently, json_decode doesn't return the array as an associative array by default, even though that is how the info was encoded. All I had to do was add the 'true' flag in my decode function call. Basically this

`json_decode($input);`

became this

`json_decode($input, true);`

and now everything works perfect. I hope this helps someone else who has the same issue. For more documentation, check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

you have this line:

```
$selectedMessage = $messagesArray[$selectedShipType];
```

but the variable `$selectedShipType` is not defined.
You only define it at the end of the template:

```
$selectedShipType = $_GET['shiptype'];
```

Comment: I apologize I realize I changed that while debugging. Moving that line to before $selectedMessage = $messagesArray[$selectedShipType]; changes nothing. :/

Comment: but do you call the page like this? `example.com/page/here/?shiptype=something_here` ? Maybe the `$_GET` parameter is not set.

Comment: Correct! The url looks like this: mywebsite.com/index.php/admin/filterSnail/?shiptype=16677. Also, the log of selected ship type returns 16677 as expected.